# how can i automatically create thumbnail images from an uploaded file With GD library 

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, gd

how can i create automatically tumbling .. I need when i upload original image automatically create thumb and add thumb ( size 200 x 200 ) in folder and insert path of thumb in database $thumb .. i need help .. any one can help me ?

```
    <?php
error_reporting(0);
if ($_POST['submit'])
{
  $name=basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);   
  $t_name=$_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
  $dir='upload';
  $image_title=$_POST['image_title'];
  $image_details=$_POST['image_details'];
  $image_text=$_POST['image_text'];
  $cat=$_POST['cat'];
  $thumb=$_POST['thumb'];

if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))
   {
mysql_select_db ($db_name,$conn);
$qur="insert into images (mid, cid, name, path, image_title, image_details, image_text, thumb, addGby, addGon) 
values('','$cat','$name','upload/$name','$image_title','$image_details','$image_text','$thumb','$session_name',now())";
$res=mysql_query($qur,$conn);
echo 'File Upload sussfully';
}
else
{
echo 'upload filed!';
}
}
?>



<form method="post" action="Addgallery.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="field">
<label>image : </label>
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="file_upload" id="file_upload"  />
</div>

<div class="field fullwidth last">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" class="bt blue large"  />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to use the GD or ImageMagick library to resize the images.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the portion of the code that uses GD? Also, have you checked phpinfo() to make sure that your server has the GD module installed?

Comment: @Andrew Thanks ..  I add Gd With My tags .. & i check My server .. it's installed .. but i cant know how i can add this function with my original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try imgBrowz0r http://freecode.com/projects/imgbrowz0r
It is a php-written plugin

Css-tricks also have a tutorial on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to write your own code try these

http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

http://davidwalsh.name/create-image-thumbnail-php

http://webcheatsheet.com/php/create_thumbnail_images.php